# Computers lose power, lights dim. I suspect the mains power supply; is there anything I can do?

Tags: electrical, uk

The lights in my sitting room sometimes dim - almost completely - for a fraction of a second. Sometimes one or both of my computers ('T' & 'M') restart unprompted at the same moment, as though they lost mains power for an instant.

I have never seen either computer lose power without the lights dimming* and I have never seen T lose power without M also losing power*. The opposite does happen; the lights dim without computers losing power, and M can lose power while T remains fine.

The computers have no parts in common, and M was built around 3 months ago with a brand new (high quality) power supply. T is approximately 6 years old and has never had problems before this. The power supplies in both are well-sized to the PCs (each can provide nearly double the theoretical power consumption of the PC).

The lighting is LED GU10s running off an auto-sensing dimmer which takes a noticeable fraction of a second to turn the lights on when it is switched (while it detects whether it should be running in leading- or trailing-edge mode).

None of the other lights in the house display this behavior, and no other appliances show the same symptoms.

I suspect that this is an issue with the power supply and would like to know what, if anything, I can do about it.

*assuming they are on at the time, of course.

Comment: Would turn off the breaker for that room/circuit, hopefully the lights and computers are on the same breaker.  Think you have either a loose connection or a broken wire inside of the wire insulation(very hard to find).  Might take time to find, so moving the computers to a new circuit might be an idea.

Comment: The lights and computers are on different breakers, unfortunately - I have no idea how these things are done elsewhere, but here in the UK electrical sockets are grouped together into one or more breakers and lights are likewise grouped, so you will rarely (almost never?) get lights and sockets on the same breaker.

Comment: Two different circuits with these problems, might mean the problem is in the breaker box, instead of somewhere in the circuit itself.  Do not count on the circuits being okay, just the first place to check is the breaker box for loose connections.  Do not know what UK allows people/homeowners to do, so might require a licensed electrician for the box.  Parts of the box might contain live power even with the main turned off, be careful or get an expert in.

Comment: @frodoskywalker of course the main exception is plug-in lights, which some people prefer to use almost to the exclusion of "the big light" on the ceiling (and illegal wiring, which I've had in a rented house). So it was worth checking which circuits are affected

Comment: Some answers/commenters have mentioned using a UPS as a workaround;  I'd just like to mention that my (APC) UPS also came with a reporting capability.  I can get a list of dates/times that voltage dropped under some threshold, etc.  If there *is* an external issue, having specific dates, times, and durations can help in troubleshooting.

Comment: This is known as a [Brownout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownout_(electricity))

Comment: In a previous house I had similar issues which culminated in unrelated circuits losing power. The source was a loose lug which arced intermittently and eventually ablated enough material to destroy the connection. I am given to understand that the arcing would be audible if one was near the breaker. I don't recall it being visible without taking the covers off

Answer (score 26):

Obviously you can put both computers onto an "Uninterruptible Power Supply" (UPS) and if the outages are short, that will keep them up, until its batteries go bad (as they always do - buying a UPS is committing to buying new batteries for it as needed...a UPS with bad batteries will die on power dips that a computer without one will survive.)

The fact that sometimes one or both computers survive a power dip is an effect of their relative load .vs. the size of their internal power supply filter capacitor, mostly.

That does not solve the apparent issue (loose, poor, or otherwise intermittent connection) with your internal house wiring, of course. You'll need to hunt that down in any case, as it's a fire hazard. It's located somewhere between the affected items and the supply. Since other parts of the house are not affected, the problem is within the house, not with the supply to the house.

You may find melted, charred or otherwise heat-damaged insulation at the location where this is happening, since an electrical arc is typically associated with each disconnection and reconnection event at a loose connection.

Whether that's DIY or call someone depends on you. Find the breaker or breakers associated with the lights and computers and turn them off before taking things apart to check them if opting to DIY.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide this answer. Is it certain that the fault must be inside the house? I had assumed that these voltage dips would not necessarily show up in other appliances, and all the lights elsewhere in the house are the sort of LEDs that take a few seconds to fully dim after switching off, so I wouldn't expect to see a half second interruption.

Comment: If your house loses power for a half-second, it will be noticeable on almost every electrical appliance, so I'd fully expect this problem to be internal, not external.

Comment: If this is a grid supply issue, it'll be affecting the whole house (and maybe your neighbours) - it may not be so apparent in other rooms though because they may have different types of lights and loads. Moving a computer around would help rule it out. If it's specific to one particular circuit, it ought to be easier to track down - I'd be inclined to call an electrician to figure it out in either case though.

Comment: If the fault is outside the house, it can be specific to a single supply phase. Considering the lights and outlet are on different breakers, it could be worth it to check if they are on the same phase.

Comment: @RalphBolton Using a computer as a fault detection device sounds like an unwise and potentially expensive proposition.

Comment: @jpa it's common to connect adjacent houses to different  phases, in sequence, so it might be worth asking the next-door-but-two neighbours if they've had issues - or all the neighbours of course

Comment: The dip is likely to be far less than half a second, even if the lights glitch for that long

Comment: @T.J.L. Your other option is to buy a logging power quality analyzer... price one of those out, they're worth 5-7 computers.

Comment: There are UPS' that display the voltage right on the device and they are far more sensitive than the lights.  They will alert you if the voltage goes out of range.  Many have data cables you can plug into the computer and with the right software you can log when the voltage drops, check current voltage, etc.

Answer (score 9):

Here in Australia I had a similar problem: one PC would switch off completely without warning, one PC died (dead motherboard), and the lights in one room would flicker (not the same room as the computers). Ultimately it turned out to be a power supply problem from the grid: too many houses had been built in the area and the power company hadn't upgraded the system. The power was low in the rest of the house, but the appliances and lights were just a little more tolerant/didn't flicker noticeably.

Our first step was to get onto an electrician, who rented us a wall mounted voltage meter. We had to manually record the reading at different times of the day: in the evening when everyone in the street was cooking, the power dropped from 240V down to about 160V.

We then went to the power company, who added their own meters inside our power box, as well as on the power lines (in the street). Ultimately they admitted the fault was theirs, and eventually upgraded the transformer for the local grid.

They refused to admit their supply damaged the computer: that had to be an insurance claim.

Comment: A plug-in mains power meter/monitor can be used to check the voltage safely, if it is brown-out.  Brown-outs were of course more obvious with incandescent lights, so the OP should check if any of those dim at the right time of day (e.g. an oven light; they're always incandescent)

Comment: BTW mains power meters are sometimes available to borrow from local energy saving schemes

Answer (score 7):

The symptoms you are describing are generally referred to as **brown-outs**, as distinct from black-outs.  Instead of a power cut, the voltage is dropping for a tiny fraction of time.  I too had this at my house where just one set of lights would dip out and 1 out of 4 computers would restart.  I ended up putting a UPS for the computer.

As mentioned already, there are many causes.  More possible causes are switching on and off of motors and loads in the house, such as washing machines, fridges, and space heaters.

Definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownout_(electricity))

> A brownout is a drop in voltage in an electrical power supply system.
>
> Unintentional brownouts can be caused by excessive electricity demand, severe weather events, or a malfunction or error affecting electrical grid control or monitoring systems. Intentional brownouts are used for load reduction in an emergency, or to prevent a total grid power outage due to high demand. The term brownout comes from the dimming of incandescent lighting when voltage reduces.

Answer (score 3):

First check if the affected computers and lights are on the same breaker.  If they are, there is most likely some loose connection on that line (or the breaker itself could be defective).  If not, you can see if there is a loose contact at the main breaker, and if that look fine, have the electricity company look at the supply lines entering the house.

I had something similar happen, and the affected appliances were *not* on the same breaker, but there were also parts of the house that were completely unaffected.  It turned out that our house has *two* power supply lines going from a mast outside to the house.  One of the lines had a loose contact, and whenever the wind pushed tree branches against this line, it would momentarily cut out.

Hope this helps.  As always, it's a good idea to have a professional check what's going on.

Comment: In the UK, it's highly unusual for lights and sockets ("receptacles") to be on the same circuit. Lights are typically wired with less substantial cable and a 5A or 6A breaker; sockets typically have a 30A breaker.

Answer (score 0):

Report it to your local supplier, the supply may be stressed due to additional local consumers, perhaps some ^&*"$£%^ may be running a bitcoin generator. They may send someone round to hook a recorder up at the mains inlet. When this happened to me, it took them over a year to get an additional supply at the sub-station built.